# Book for probability and various probability distribution functions.

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request, statistical-inference

Please suggest a book/books where i can understand

1. Probability theory (with lots of example and solution)
2. examples on permutations and combinations.
3. list of all probability distribution functions, and their mathematical derivation. (I have good understanding on differential and integral calculus)
4. A case study where some random experiment is conducted and data is analysed as some standard probability distribution function.
5. From above case study how meta data is extracted from Probability distribution functions.

Comment: Schaum's outline on Probability and Statistics explains concepts in terms of questions and answers. Can serve as a book with "examples".

Comment: @shyamupa thanks for quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently researched a lot for finding good stuff on Probability . I would suggest you to have a look at [this](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/) . This is undergraduate course of probability taught in MIT . The professor is very good . You will have lots of resources on this site

`1.Video Lectures`

`2.Assignments`

`3.Tutorials and Quizs`

Comment: video lectures are amazing, thanx a ton, really appreciate it :)